# How can I dump hard disk with selected partition in DVD and restore it when needed?

Tags: backup, dvd, system-restore, dump

I want to dump hard disk with installed Operating System and all other Software with their configuration into DVDs. Definitely requires more DVDs. Is there any free tool which can manage to dump in multiple DVDs in such way that from those DVDs, I can restore or dump back all things in Hard disk with the same state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) for this purpose for quite some time. It allows you to create an image of a hard drive, archive it, and restore that image. It allows you do to this via DVD-r, hard drive, or even over the network. It's a free ISO image that you burn to a CD.

Comment: For Clonezilla, I found that it can not restore files from images but then found that there are 2 types Clonezilla Live and SE. So, the limitation is for Live only ?

Answer (score 0):

What you require is a system imaging tool, there are a number of free ones available, see here for more info:
http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-drive-imaging-program.htm#Quick_Selection_Guide

Comment: Thank you for the link but I already have seen the list but couldn't reach to the conclusion which to use due to lack of experience on such stuff. Can you recommend with your experience according to my requirements ?

Comment: I personally use Acronis TrueImage which is paid for software but I'd probably say Paragon would be best for you to use as a beginner. I've also used CloneZilla with success but it's not the friendliest package ever...! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had great success with Symantec System Recovery.  It used to be called Backup Exec System recovery as well.  There is a free trial available.  The boot disk is simple as you just burn an ISO.  You can also restore to different hardware or convert to/from a VM. While not free, it does an excellent job and is simple to use.

[Symantec System Recovery](http://www.symantec.com/business/products/family.jsp?familyid=backupexec)

Comment: But as it's not free, I cannot use it with full functionality, right ?
Can I do what I have asked in question in free trial version ?

Comment: I have not tried the latest but you could in earlier versions.